# Xcom column does not exist in Airflow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm trying to spin up a lightweight docker container with airflow, which ultimately led me to replace the CeleryExecutor from the official airflow `docker-compose.yaml` (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) with a LocalExecutor , which results in the following :

```
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- matplotlib }

  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins


  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
     .....long bash script
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

And my Dockerfile being:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow

WORKDIR $AIRFLOW_HOME

USER root
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install vim -qqq && apt-get install -y python3-pip

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

USER $AIRFLOW_UID
```

All the containers are healthy , but when I try to perform `airflow tasks test {{dag}} {{task}} {{date}}` , I get the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column xcom.execution_date does not exist
```

Additionally, when I check the existence of my dags , `airflow dags list` shows the expected outcome. Could you please let me know how I could solve this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Were you able to find an solution for this?

Comment: @henadzit Actually yes! What happened is that I had airflow in two localtions locally and I was using the cli in the wrong location. You should inspect your `/usr/airflow` and then change your location into it , see if it works there & to the same with all other possible locations airflow may be installed. Be sure to have it in only one location - to avoid these types of cofusions

Comment: Glad to hear that! Unfortunately my issue is related to MWAA (Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow). I don't have control over the folder where they run CLI :) I opened a ticket for AWS, let's see what they reply.

Comment: @henadzit Oh man! AWS , wish you good luck!